# How to access method annotation inside an advice using AspectJ?

Tags: spring, annotations, aspectj, interceptor

I have created an aspect to intercept certain methods before their execution as follows using AspectJ

```
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class SomeAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(com.test.package.MyCustomAnnotation)")
    public void validateSearchRestriction(final JoinPoint jp,
                           final MyCustomAnnotation annotation) {
        final String useCase = annotation.useCase();
    }
}
```

The custom annotation written is as follows

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecurityRestricted {
    String useCase();
}
```

The problem I am facing is with the second argument in my method.
If I try to get the annotation in my aspect as a second argument, the application fails to start with the below error.

Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301) ~[aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]

If I remove the second argument, my application starts fine. 
Is this the right way to get the method annotation?

Comment: Rewrite your Pointcut to `@annotation(annotation)`, where `annotation` is the name of your method argument. This way it should bind to the parameter in your method signature.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a ton! Cheers!

Comment: @M.Deinum do you think it is worth writing an answer? If yes, please do it. Else, I will do that. This sure helped m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind variables from a pointcut to a method you will need to references the variable from the pointcut. So instead of writing `@annotation(your.CustomAnnotation)` you should write `@annotation(method-argument-name)`.

So in your case your pointcut would look like

```
@Before(“@annotation(annotation)”)
public void validateSearchRestriction(JoinPoint jp, MyCustomAnnotation annotation) { ... }
```